# Is it safe to use Google Cloud Signed URLs for anonymous user uploads directly from the browser?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pre-signed-url

A Google Cloud signed URL looks like this, which seems pretty insecure to give to an anonymous user to upload a file from the browser:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucketname/mypath.extension
  ?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256
  &X-Goog-Credential=my-service-account-name@myprojectname.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2Fsomenumber%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request
  &X-Goog-Date=20240209T090634Z
  &X-Goog-Expires=7200
  &X-Goog-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost
  &X-Goog-Signature=somehash
```

The fact that it includes `mybucketname` is probably okay, but `my-service-account-name@myprojectname` for the IAM service? And then I'm unsure what you can unpack from the `Goog-Signature`, if it's safe to give to anonymous users or they can hack into it to escalate access somehow.

I was planning (after advice from several developers on the web), to get a signed URL, and use that signed URL to upload directly from the browser a large file like a video, so it takes the shortest path and doesn't need to go through the server. But is it safe? Or should I do it another way?

Comment: SignedURL process is safe and you can't escalate to have more permission. However, how much do you trust anonymous user on internet? They will be able to upload large video on your bucket. Bucket you own, you pay and you are legally responsible. What about illegal videos? So your solution is technically safe, but legally dangerous for you! Request registration, recaptcha, email validation, term of use,...

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere what does https://cloudconvert.com or another similar site do, which allows arbitrary content upload by anonymous users? The legal aspects you are describing.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not a legal person. I will be personally scary! I'm sure there is a clear term of use that is only a technical platform and not a content hosting platform, therefore they are not responsible on the content. You should review that part with legal expert. Once done, the signedURL is fine, and add lifecycle on Cloud Storage to delete automatically object after a while.

Comment: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99565/how-to-prevent-legal-issues-when-allowing-anonymous-users-to-upload-arbitrary-co

Comment: No, it is not safe and I would not implement that in an uncontrolled environment. You have no control over the content and in some cases, you might have a legal problem. 2) Knowing the service account email address is not a problem. 3) The signature is a hash and that is safe as well. 4) No they cannot hack into your system based on the Signed URL. 5) Using Signed URLs for read access is OK, but not for write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signed URLs contain authentication information in their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform specific actions on a resource. When you generate a signed URL, you specify a user or service account which must have sufficient permission to make the request that the signed URL will make. After you generate a signed URL, anyone who possesses it can use the signed URL to perform specified actions, such as reading an object, within a specified period of time.

Using signed URLs to upload files directly from the browser to Google Cloud Storage is generally considered safe, but there are some security considerations to keep in mind.Explained clearly in this [blog](https://medium.com/miro-engineering/using-signed-urls-to-simplify-data-uploads-623635ceb769) Using signed URLs to simplify data uploads by Emerick Bosch

**Signed URLs can be used by anyone while they are valid.**

**Signed URLs do not perform data validation.**

**Using signed URLs does not remove the need to have an authority for storage access.**

**Authorization for a signed URL occurs when it is used, not when it is created.**

Signed URLs (uploads) for anonymous accounts. Rethink why you want anonymous users to upload anything. Fraud and identity impersonation is already too easy today. They will be able to upload large videos on your bucket. Bucket you own, you pay and you are legally responsible.Sites which allow anonymous users to upload content, they implement various measures to address legal risks. As guillaume blaquiere mentioned,you should review that  with a legal expert.